# How to check for EOF with `read_line()`?

Tags: rust

Given the code below, how can I specifically check for EOF? Or rather, how can I distinguish between "there's nothing here" and "it exploded"?

```
match io::stdin().read_line() {
    Ok(l) => print!("{}", l),
    Err(_) => do_something_else(),
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [documentation for `read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

> If successful, this function will return the total number of bytes read.
>
> If this function returns `Ok(0)`, the stream has reached EOF.

This means we can check for a successful value of zero:

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut empty: &[u8] = &[];
    let mut buffer = String::new();

    let bytes = empty.read_line(&mut buffer)?;
    if bytes == 0 {
        println!("EOF reached");
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: does not handle blank line case (at least not in windows with edition 2018). you will need to check file size as well.

Comment: On Windows (at least here on Windows 11 in PowerShell 7), you can match blank lines with `Ok(1)` (a successful `read_line` that produced only one byte, which was simply `\n`). See [this example on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=087bd13ad85b0bfa58cf1e0e86560f8d).

Comment: the function is blocking - this means that if there is nothing there, we'll have to wait and block until we get a newline. So the scenario of "there's nothing here" will never actualize. only eof and actual input.