# Detect EndOfFile IoResult when reading a file

Tags: io, rust

I'm trying to read from a file in Rust. The thing I don't understand is: when the `BufferedReader` is at the EOF, it actually gives an `Err(IoError {kind: EndOfFile})` and I don't know how to match on it.

```
loop {
  match file.read_line() {
    Ok(line) => {
      // Do stuff
    },
    // Err(EndOfFile) => is want I want here so I can call "break"
    Err(_) => {
      panic!("Unexpected error reading file.");
    }
  }
}
```

How can I explicitly match the `EndOfFile` enum variant?

Comment: When a pattern match is insufficient, you can always use [match guards](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/book/patterns.html): `Err(e) if e.kind == EndOfFile => ...` for example. Not sure if that's the best here though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I would want to avoid that. Maybe there is a different approach that I can take that would change my control flow, but make it easier to `read_line()` until EOF.

Comment: I totally understand, but I don't know better (lack of experience on my part, most probably) thus why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for EOF with \`read\_line()\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475113/how-to-check-for-eof-with-read-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I explicitly match the EndOfFile enum variant?

You can match it without additional nested match using following pattern:

```
loop {
  match file.read_line() {
    Ok(line) => {
      // Do stuff
    },
    Err(IoError { kind: EndOfFile, .. }) =>
      break,
    Err(_) => {
      panic!("Unexpected error reading file.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer to your question. @ker's response is the solution to your problem. ^_^ This is how `lines` is implemented itself.

Comment: This indeed is exactly the answer to my question. Upvoted @ker just because it's actually a better flow.

Comment: Another possibility is to write `Err(e) if e.kind == EndOfFile => `, but pattern matching is probably better.

Answer (score 4):

specifically for iterating over lines rust has the `lines` function for Buffers (http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufferPrelude.html#tymethod.lines).

In your case you would loop over the lines, and once EOF is reached the loop aborts automatically without your intervention.

```
for line in file.lines() {
    match line {
        Ok(line) => {
            // do stuff
        },
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Unexpected error reading file.")
        }
    }
}
```

or, if your function returns a compatible `Result` you can use the try! macro for less noise:

```
fn myfun(file: File) -> IoResult<()> {
    for line in file.lines() {
        let line = try!(line);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks much better than what I have. I might just avoid doing a nasty Struct pattern match, thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like rust post 1.0 has changed `IoError` to `std::io::Error`. Also, `kind` is now hidden in the internals. I had to use a [guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#guards) to work for a similar type issue (`WouldBlock` instead of `EndOfFile`).

e.g.

```
match some_method_that_might_block() {
    Ok(_) => {
        debug!("worked!");
    },
    Err(ref e @ IoError { kind: std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock, .. }) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
        // ignore WouldBlock
    },
    Err(e) => { debug!("error={:?}", e); }
};
```

Comment: In fact, now in Rust EOF condition on a `Read` is signaled by returning 0 (a number of bytes read).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this on a modern version of rust post 1.0, [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html) now stipulate that reaching the end of a file while attempting to read from it is definitively *not* an error and should be represented with an `Ok(0)` (much like other programming languages/frameworks) rather than a hard error.

Since you can directly match against the number of bytes read (unlike `std::io::error` where the `ErrorKind` member is hidden and cannot be matched against directly), that makes handling it very easy:

```
        let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        loop {
            let bytes_read = match file.read(&mut buf) {
                Ok(0) => break, // end-of-file
                Ok(n) => n,
                Err(e) => // handle error however you see fit,
            };
```