# How can I match on a specific io::Error type?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am trying to read in a file until the end 2 bytes at a time and I want to catch the EOF error:

```
use byteorder::{BigEndian, ReadBytesExt}; // 1.3.4
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let filename = "/etc/hosts";
    let mut file = File::open(filename).expect("Cannot open file");
    loop {
        let binary = match file.read_u16::<BigEndian>() {
            Ok(binary) => binary,
            Err(e) => panic!("Can't read from file: {}, err {}", filename, e),
            // Can I catch the EOF error here?
        };
        println!("{:?}", binary);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

This works in Rust version 1.17.0 (and probably back to Rust 1.0):

```
let binary = match file.read_u16::<BigEndian>() {
    Err(ref e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::UnexpectedEof => break,
    Err(e) => panic!("Can't read from file: {}, err {}", filename, e),
    Ok(binary) => binary,
};
```

Answer (score 12):

I find...

```
Err(e) => match e.kind() {
    EndOfFile => break,
    SomeOtherError => do_something(),
    _ => panic!("Can't read from file: {}, err {}", filename, e),
},
```

... to be more readable than...

```
Ok(binary) => binary,
Err(ref e) if e.kind() == EndOfFile => break,
Err(ref e) if e.kind() == SomeOtherError => do_something(),
Err(e) => panic!("Can't read from file: {}, err {}", filename, e),
```

(I'm not sure what other errors we could expect to get...)

In other situations where the match guards might not be the same - the way that we're repeating `e.kind()` - we couldn't use the nested `match`.

This works as of Rust 1.25.

Answer (score 8):

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and does not apply to stable Rust 1.0 `io::Error`. The *concept* of nested pattern matching still applies in other contexts.

You can match the kind as part of the pattern, using some more advanced features of pattern matching:

```
Err(IoError { kind: IoErrorKind::EndOfFile, .. }) => break,
Err(e) => panic!("Can't read from file: {}, err {}", filename, e),
```

The first variant means “an `Err` containing an `IoError` where `kind` is `IoErrorKind::EndOfFile` and all the other fields are whatever you like”. The second then means “any other `Err`, binding the contained value to the variable name `e`”.

Comment: Does this still work? `IoError` appears different these days, and the closest I came still resulted in *error[E0026]: struct `std::io::Error` does not have a field named `kind`*

Comment: @sarnold: `std::io::Error` now conceals its fields so that you can’t edit the kind of an `Error` object; it does, however, have a *method* [`kind()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.kind) which returns the kind. Now I’d recommend something more like `Err(ref e) if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::EndOfFile => break,`.

Comment: Thanks, nice to know that I didn't miss something obvious.

Comment: Side note: these days the rust documentation is explicit that "no more bytes to read" should always be `Ok(0)` and not `ErrorKind::EndOfFile`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of matching a [MySQL `IoError`](https://docs.rs/mysql/16.0.2/mysql/enum.Error.html#variant.IoError):

```
match pool.prep_exec("SELECT SLEEP(10)", ()) {
    Ok(_) => (),
    Err(mysql::Error::IoError(e)) => {
        eprintln!("IoError: {}", e);
        do_something();
    }
    Err(e) => {
        eprintln!("{}", e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I changed this line to check the error type!  Hope this helps others.

```
Err(e) => if e.kind == IoErrorKind::EndOfFile { break } else { panic!("Can't read from file: {}, err {}", filename, e) },
```

Comment: This is not a very readable solution. Have a look at Chris' Answer and at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068807/detect-endoffile-ioresult-when-reading-a-file