# How can I match against a std::io::Error with a Windows error code?

Tags: error-handling, rust, match

In my tiny little Rust program, I'm calling a Windows API and want to make sure that everything went OK. In order to do so, I'm using the functionality provided by `std::io::Error::last_os_error()`. I also want to deliberately ignore some of the errors that may occur.

I could not find any information on how to do that, other than just printing out the `Error` returned by that function. What I actually need is a kind of a match statement in which I can handle the various known errors.

I understand that the function returns an `std::io::Error` struct but I could not find any information on error IDs or similar concepts.

Currently, my code reads like

```
use std::io::Error;

fn main() {
    // do some stuff that may lead to an error

    match Error::last_os_error() {
        163 => // Do nothing. This error is to be expected
        // _ =>  Err("Something went wrong "),
    }
}
```

The actual problem is that `last_os_error()` returns an error struct but I want to match on the ID of the error that is listed in WinError.h (this program only runs under Windows).

Can anybody help me on how to distinguish the various errors behind the error structs in such a match statement?

Comment: @Shepmaster you are right. The post was really poorly written. Apologies for that. Maybe this is part of my problem. It's very hard for me to even find the correct words, describing my question. I just edited the post and hope that my question becomes more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`io::Error::raw_os_error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.raw_os_error) to get the original error code and then match against that:

```
match Error::last_os_error().raw_os_error() {
    Some(163) => {} // Do nothing. This error is to be expected
    Some(e) => panic!("Unknown OS error {}", e),
    None => panic!("Not an OS error!"),
}
```

---

It's a different question of whether this is a good idea or not. You can [also match against known error types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28491759/155423). I'd recommend using that where possible. You may also want to create (or find) an enum that maps the various error codes to human-readable values, as it's a lot easier to tell that you meant `NotEnoughMemory` instead of `SecurityDescriptorInvalid` than it is to tell the difference of `123` and `132`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess that this is the function I have been looking for. Unfortunately, when running the code, I get the following error now:
thread '<main>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: MissingNulError(Some([99, 58, 92, 116, 101, 115, 116, 92, 116, 101, 115, 116, 46, 116, 120, 116]))', ../src/libcore\result.rs:785
This does not seem to be related to the use of the panic! macro but to the lines before.

Comment: @Norbert that seems like it belongs in a separate question. We prefer different questions because that makes it possible for other people to find the question and answer for themselves. Would *you* look at a question with the title "How can I match against a std::io::Error with a Windows error code" to understand what a `MissingNulError` is? Make sure you produce another [MCVE] when asking the new question, including *just* the code required to produce the error.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I assumed that the error had to do with the solution that you suggested in your post but after having a 2nd look, this is obviously not the case. I guess I'll try to figure it out myself first before asking another question. Thanks!