# How to check for EOF in read_line in Rust 1.12?

Tags: rust

Consider the following program, how do I detect EOF in stdin and break the loop?

```
use std::io;
use std::process;

fn main() {
    let mut sum = 0;
    loop {
        let mut number_str = String::new();
        match io::stdin().read_line(&mut number_str) {
            Ok(n) => {},
            Err(e) => { println!("ERROR: got '{}' when reading a line", e) }
        }
        match number_str.trim().parse::<i32>() {
            Err(n) => {
                println!("ERROR: Entered something that is not a number: '{}'",
                    number_str.trim_right());
                process::exit(1)
            },
            Ok(n) => { sum += n }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: there is an [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27475113/1091116) but the answer seems to be out of date anymore, which is why I added a version number in the question title.

Comment: I would also welcome any style improvements here, in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for `read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

> If this reader is currently at EOF then this function will not modify `buf` and will return `Ok(n)` where `n` is the number of bytes which were read.

Comment: so in this case it will be Ok(0)?

Comment: @d33tah yes, I believe so. I can't imagine where any other number would come from, the wording is a bit ambiguous, isn't it?

Comment: The documentation isn't all that clear, but what happens if the remaining input is a partial line?  Is it returned as a line, or is it discarded?